# own function VBA else will not execute

Tags: vba, if-statement

Hi I have absolutly no clue why the else with "exit for" will not execute.

Value of my respective Excel testing cell as follows:

"VERS.GR.III, KENNNR.1905, V        ERS.NR. 1023461"

```
Function DebitorVorhanden(Debitor As String) As Boolean
    Dim Ausgabe As Boolean
    Ausgabe = False
    Dim TextLänge As Integer
    TextLänge = Len(Debitor)
    Dim Prüfer As Integer
    
    For Prüfer = 1 To TextLänge
        If Mid(Debitor, Prüfer, 1) = "1" Then

            Dim PrüferLänge As Integer
            PrüferLänge = 0
            
            Dim Prüfer2 As Integer
            
            For Prüfer2 = Prüfer To Prüfer + 6
                
                If Int(Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1)) = 1 Or 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5 Or 6 Or 7 Or 8 Or 9 Then
                        PrüferLänge = PrüferLänge + 1
                    Else
                        Exit For
                End If
                
            Next Prüfer2
            
            If PrüferLänge = 7 Then
                Ausgabe = True
                GoTo DebitorGefunden
            End If
            
        End If
    Next Prüfer
    
DebitorGefunden:
    DebitorVorhanden = Ausgabe
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Int(Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1)) = 1 Or 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5 Or 6 Or 7 Or 8 Or 9 Then
```

is always true and therefore the if case is running. The `Or 2` statements return the value 2 and do not compare the two to the int(...) value.

A working solution would be:

```
dim tmp
tmp=Int(Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1))
If tmp=1 or tmp=2 or tmp=3 Then
```

A shorter ways is:

```
If InStr("123456789", Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) ) Then
```

Comment: unfortunately neither long or short will bring a result on my side

Comment: this is now working `If Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "0" Or Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "1" Or Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "2" Or Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "3" Or Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "4" Or Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "5" Or Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "6" Or Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "7" Or Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "8" Or Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1) = "9" `

Comment: @Bigbe Thank you. I fixed it. 
Also: the shorter version should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The `Or` operator "performs a logical disjunction on two expressions."
So expressions on either side of the operator are treated entirely separately.
Meaning that for it to work, it would have to be something like this:

```
If Int(Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1)) = 1 Or Int(Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1)) = 2 Or Int(Mid(Debitor, Prüfer2, 1)) = 3....
```

There are several ways to solve the problem; a common approach to handle numbers would be to use the [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement), as you can do things like `Case 1 To 9`

*But I like the InStr approach by Samuel*